# Какой язык выбрать для Android?

Tags: android

Знаю знаю, вопросов таких много, как и ответов. Простите народ, но хочу получить на личный свой.
Только начинаю изучать языки, опыта нету. Акцент ставил на Java, но читаю что многие пишут что он больше для серверных или ПО
Интересует создание приложений, на Андроид и язык который не устарел, и будет популярен еще.
Для опытных вопрос дурацкий, кривой, и тд, все знаю)
И объясню еще момент, хочу такой язык, в котором я смогу "побыстрее" реализоваться, выполнять хотя бы какие нибудь работы на фрилансе и тд, чтоб плавно перейти с обычной работы полностью сюда

Comment: Кроме Java и Kotlin других (адекватных) вариантов больше в общем-то и нет, учите оба например

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть только два варианта:

Java - долгое время основной язык разработки, огромное количество примеров, библиотек, гайдов, комьюниии и вот этого всего. Множество качественной литературы даже на русском, как по языку, так и по андроид. в ближайшем обозримом будущем Java будет основным языком разработки Android, здесь максимально быстрый старт в силу просто огромной базы накопленных знаний и решений.

Kotlin - стремительно набирает популярность, много синтетического сахара, гибкость, активно продвигается, как новый язык андроид.  Относительно мало литературы и она в основном на английском, в качестве первого языка будет сложнее в силу этого.

Фактически Kotlin - java-наследник, у них много общего и зная Java освоить Kotlin будет очень просто. Разработка под андроид позволяет в одном проекте использовать сразу оба эти языка, поэтому я бы рекомендовал начинать с Java и в качестве "развлечения" постепенно переводить уже работающие проекты на Kotlin, когда освоите его в достаточной степени, использовать только его изначально.

ps: есть еще flutter с языком Dart .. но это для любителей острых ощущений пока что, проект в бэте, информации мало ..