# Языки программирования

Tags: android, ios

Какой язык программирования лучше всего подойдёт при создании  приложения для android и iOS? Более простой для новичка.

Comment: Для Андроид вроде бы Ява сейчас главный язык. Для iOS у Эппла свои языки всякие там Objective-C и Swift-ы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/915488/177345 . flutter позволит написать одно приложение под обе платформы.

Answer (score 3):

На вашем случае, лучше всего подойдёт язык "html"...