# Какой язык программирования под Android изучать?

Tags: android

Я хочу научиться программировать под Android, но не знаю что для этого изучать. Какой язык программирования сейчас нужен для Android? Java? Kotlin? Что-то другое?

На данный момент в программировании я ноль, но очень хочу развиваться в этом направлении. Пусть даже не профессионально, я просто получаю от этого удоволствие, мне это нравиться.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какой язык выбрать для Android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/915474/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-android)

Answer (score 6):

**Kotlin** - это язык без которого сейчас в Android никак. На *"Google I/O 2019"* гуглы официально установили его как приоритетный.

Большинство компаний сейчас пишут новый код на Kotlin.

**НО!** Есть одно жирное **НО!** Без Java никуда. Потому, что никто не отменял Legacy, никто не отменял документации на Java. Да и Kotlin основан на Java. Если вы не будете знать Kotlin то скорее всего потеряете 2/3 потенциальных вакансий. Если вы не будете знать Java вас вообще вряд-ли куда-то возьмут работать.

Поэтому ответ таков: **Оба!** Учите Java, как только поймете, что вы ее знаете хорошо переходите на Kotlin. Зная Java перейти на Kotlin большого труда не составит, а вот обратное неверно.

**PS:**

Ну и в догонку скажу. Java легче для понимания новичкам. Так как в ней все более явно описано. Kotlin имеет огромную кучу синтаксического сахара и если это ваш первый язык вам будет трудно. Так что Java потом Kotlin=)

Comment: Большое спасибо за разъяснение. Кратко и понятно. Теперь понял куда и главное как двигаться дальше. Очень вам благодарен :)

Answer (score 1):

Java является официальным языком для разработки Android и поддерживается Android Studio.

Kotlin - хороший язык програмирования для Андроид.

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/05/google-io-2019-empowering-developers-to-build-experiences-on-Android-Play.html. В данный момент Kotlin является приоритетным языком программирования под Android