# На каком языке программирования лучше писать Android-приложения: Java или Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, мобильная-разработка

Расскажите, какой из этих двух языков вы выбрали для мобильной разработки и на чём основан ваш выбор. Да, я понимаю, что вопрос довольно философский и можно ответить "да на чём тебе удобно", но интересуют конкретные плюсы и минусы в отношении каждого языка за счёт архитектуры, фреймворков, интеграции и т. д.

Comment: Если вы новичок и хотите работать с Android — учите Kotlin. В остальных случаях я бы выбрал Java

Comment: @AzizUmarov новичков и сразу на котлин?) Что за остальные случаи?

Comment: Вы не новый программист, знаете другие языки, ..... вообще не начинающий программист и цель Андроид

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какой язык выбрать для Android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/915474/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-android)

Comment: Под андроид надо учить котлин, другой вопрос, что не зная джавы, котлин выучить мягко говоря тяжело. У котлина вся документация в духе "это сделано как на джаве, а вот тот как на джаве только тут немного поменяли".

Comment: Мой выбор был - сначала писать на Java, ибо семплов дофига в инете, да и выбора особо не было :D. Когда гугл официально признал Kotlin - сразу же перешел на него, т.к. меньше кода: null-safety, coroutine, extension, а в связке с androidx и jetpack так ваще малина. Все это позволяет мне в итоге делать все тоже, только за меньшее время. Если у вас много времени, не ленитесь и изучите Java - лишним не будет, на собеседах все равно будут спрашивать по ней. А как поймете, что все как-то громоздко и занимает много времени - то Kotlin в помощь.

Comment: уже был пару дней назад такой вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1154481/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-android-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c, как бы то ни было, ответом будет: нужно учить оба языка

Comment: Писать на Kotlin, потому что Kotlin First. 
Знать Java, потому что это основы и Must Have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы однозначно порекомендовал бы Java. Kotlin - новомодная штука, которая как взлетела, также может и "упасть". А Java вам может пригодиться не только для Andriod. Знание Java значительно помогает в изучении и использовании Kotlin, но не наоборот. Своей раскрученностью Kotlin обязан в большей степени эффективным менеджерам JetBrains, т.к. официальными языками для Andriod Google и раньше признавал многие другие JVM языки программирования, но про это не кричали на каждом углу. А завтра они вообще запустят какую-нибудь Фуксию и без Java, и без Kotlin. С Java не пропадёте, ваша ценность и стоимость как программиста будет намного выше.

Comment: Только Java и Kotlin были и пока оба есть офф. языки разработки. "признавал многие другие JVM языки" -- ваша фантазия. Не вводите людей в заблуждение.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы новичок и хотите работать с Android — учите Kotlin. В остальных случаях я бы выбрал Java.

Вопрос действительно философский.
Kotlin - код короче за счет современного синтаксиса. Время на разработку и тестирование меньше.  Kotlin-разработчики могут использовать Java-фреймворки и библиотеки и писать более понятный и простой код.

Я думаю, что в ближайшее время Java все равно будет самой популярной. Аргументацию можно почитать [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/461877/)

Comment: оригинал тут: https://habr.com/ru/post/461877/

Answer (score 1):

Учите kotlin, но если честно, то надо знать оба языка.
Почему kotlin,
Во-первых он имеет более лаконичный синтаксис и писать и читать намного легче.
Во вторых kotlin Google  выбрала приоритетным языком, и теперь именно он является основным.
В третьих в android не полноценная современная java а ее урезана версия, и на фоне конфликтов  Google и Oracle вряд ли она будет
Но если вы планируете android не как хобби, а как ремесло, то скорее всего вам потребуется поддерживать старый код на java, плюс многие компании хоть и переходят на kotlin  делают это очень медленно.
Так же по kotlin не всегда удается найти ответ для решение какой либо проблемы, а на java ответ есть, и зная оба языка вы без проблем портируете его