# На каком уровне стоит изучить Java для Android разработки?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Я так понимаю хватит знания Java Core?
Пару дней смотрел новые вакансии, не разу не увидел новых проектов на Java (что не удивительно конечно), только Kotlin. Стоит ли практиковаться в написании приложений сразу на Kotlin, или лучше начать с Java?

Comment: Синтаксис языка, коллекции и ООП.

Comment: Именно для Андроид разработки нужно уметь в Андроид разработку) Только Core (синтаксиса, коллекций и ООП) ИМХО не достаточно.

Comment: Kotlin или Java - это вопрос скорее риторический в среде мобильной разработки)) 
Недавно поднимали обсуждение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1155870/%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-android-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-java-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-kotlin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Вам нужно знать весь **Core Java**. Знать `java.collections`. Понимать хорошо ООП. Это прям основа без которой никуда.
- Стоит ознакомиться с многопоточностью. Но только ознакомиться, на уровне понимания как она работает в Java, т.к. в Android для асинхронной работы используются свои фреймворки.

  Стоит так же ознакомиться с работой с файлами, но опять же на базовом уровне. Это не очень часто используется, а если понадобиться потом разобраться больших проблем не будет.
- Вас не интересует Java выше 8ой, т.к. в Android ее нет в принципе.

  - Исключения: `java.util.{Map,Collection,Comparator}` и `java.time`. Подробнее [тут](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring).

  Вас не интересуют стримы - их никто не использует в Android разработке.

  Вас не интересуют практически никакие Java библиотеки (например Spring).

  Вас не интересуют ничего что связано с UI на Java.

Важно понимать, что Android это очень большой фреймворк в котором от Java только основы. Все остальное там свое.

Поэтому если условно разделить время от старта обучения до получения первой работы у вас на Java должно уйти примерно 20% времени.

Как только вы поняли, что понимаете основы Java вы начинаете учить Android.

**UPD Про Kotlin:**

Без Kotlin-a сейчас в Android почти никуда. Но тут есть нюансы.

- Зная Java - начать писать на Kotlin проблем вообще не составит. 2-4 недели.
- Никто не отменял легаси кода на Java.
- Большинство фреймворка Android написано на Java и его нужно понимать.
- Да и большинство компаний которые пишут на чистом Kotlin у вас все равно спросят Java
- Java намного легче для вхождения т.к. там все более явно описано чем в Kotlin. Это не круто для тех кто шарит, но намного круче для тех кто учится.

Так что вывод такой: Учите Java, как только поймете, что ее понимаете хорошо - учите Kotlin. Но не наоборот.

Comment: Насчет выше 8ой не соглашусь, как минимум что нового в `java.util.{Map,Collection,Comparator}` и `java.time` достойны внимания. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring

Comment: Ну выборочно, то что вы привели истинно. Дополню ответ. Мне почему-то казалось, что это все ще до Java 8. Спасибо за подсказку